# How do repair an unvented drain line that is hooked to the soil pipe

Tags: plumbing

Someone attached a shower drain line to the soil pipe which is not vented allowing sewer gas to enter the drain line (bathroom). How can this be repaired?

Comment: Need a lot more info. Is the plumbing below the shower drain accessible (e.g., in ceiling, in the ground, under the floor on raised foundation, in the wall, buried in concrete, etc.)? Can you confirm that there is a trap installed below the drain? What type of drain pipe are we talking about (plastic, iron...)? Is there an accessible vent stack nearby? How about some pictures?

Answer (score 1):

Add a vent line to a plumbing vent leading out of the building (usually more difficult) or add a mechanical vent (usually easier, but requires occasional replacement, as they do fail.) They fail less often the further you get them from the wet part of the drain, though, so mount it as high as possible. But accessible for replacement.

Mechanical vents are also known as air admittance valves, and by the brand-name of one maker "Studor" (no endorsement implied, but some folks only know them by that name, even if the one they are pointing you to on the shelf is some other brand.)

*Third possibility* is that there is already a mechanical vent, and it just needs to be replaced as it has failed.